# flash - getting keyboard focus without clicking

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In an Actionscript 3 program I used this code to add an event listener to a TextField:

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleText);
```

handleText() only gets called if I click on the TextField. Is there a way to receive keyboard events when the mouse is just hovering over the TextField (no need to click)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TextField has its own keyboard event listener that it uses to alter text, if its mode is `input`. And to capture keyboard events while your target does not have focus, add the listener to `stage`, and check if your mouse is over the text field in question. For this, you can set a boolean flag in `MOUSE_OVER` and drop it in `MOUSE_OUT` listener attached to the textfield. Then, if the flag is on, you can either parse the keyboard event yourself or transfer it to the TextField via `dispatchEvent()` call with existing `KeyboardEvent` object.